# Why does $10^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv \pm1 \pmod p$ when $p \nmid 10$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

By using Fermat's little theorem, the following:
$$10^{p-1}\equiv 1 \text{(mod p)}$$
is true, given that p does not divide 10.

By substituting in prime numbers $7,11,13,15,21,23$ etc. and picking random larger prime numbers such as 127, 199 etc., I found that 
$10^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv \text{always either }1 \text{ or }-1\text{(mod p)}$, and nothing else, so I wondered why and tried to prove by contradiction:

Assume $10^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\not \equiv ±1 \text{(mod p)}$, then $10^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv(p±k)^2\equiv k^2 \text{(mod p)}$ where $k^2≠1,$ but $k^2$ still can be some large number such that $k^2=M\cdot p±1, M\in \mathbb{Z}$, so I cannot prove it still.

Is there any method to prove that $k^2=M\cdot p±1, M\in \mathbb{Z}$ cannot be true, or can this actually be possible? Or is there better approaches to proving?

Comment: The formula you quote is certainly not Fermat's *last* theorem.

Comment: Right, I made a typo, have corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $10^{(p-1)/2}\equiv1{\pmod{p}}$ so that $10^{(p-1)/2}$ is a solution to $$x^2\equiv1\pmod{p}\iff(x-1)(x+1)\equiv0\pmod{p}$$

Since $p$ is prime, $p|(x+1)$ or $p|(x-1).$

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this is true is very simple: set $x=10^{\tfrac{p-1}2}$. You have $x^2=1$, so as $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$ is a field since $p$ is prime, this quadratic equation can't have more than two solutions.

Comment: Is it possible for you to elaborate on field? Sorry, but I am not familiar with that topic yet.

Comment: A field is simply a set with two operations with the same properties (including that non-zero elements have multiplicative inverses) as $\mathbf Q,\mathbf R$ or $\mathbf C$. The main point is that, on a field (or an integral domain such a $\mathbf Z$), a polynomial of degree $n$ can't have more than $n$ roots. Is it clearer?

Comment: Yes, it is mostly clear, apart from " two operations with the same properties", what does the 2 operations refer to?

Comment: An addition and a multiplication.

Comment: @LHC2012 if you look at saulspatz's answer, the essential ingredients that make it work is that in $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$ it makes sense to add and multiply, there is distributivity that allows you to say that $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$, and there are no zero divisors which allows you to say that $(x-1)(x+1)=0\implies [x-1=0$ OR $x+1=0]$ so that $x^2=1$ has only two solutions. All these properties together make the definition of a field.